# Using for-loop to fill vector in R

Tags: r

I'm simplifying this question, for clarity.

Say I want to create a vector with a number of elements with the value zero. I then want to use a for-loop to replace every element with its own index number inside the vector.

Can this be done?

```
K <- 11
p <- rep(0, K + 1)
for (k in 0:K) {
p[k+1] <- .... ?
}
```

Comment: You're using `k` twice inside `dyhper`. Is the second `k` supposed to be the index or `20`?

Comment: Oh, you're right. I've renamed the second k, which refers to the variable that is set on line 3, to l. To be a bit more clear, in the place where I have written x[x+1], I simply want to insert the index number of element k in 'k in 0:K'. So for the first 'k', the index number should 0, so 0 should be the first variable of the dhyper function.

Comment: So like this: `for (i in 0:K) p[i] <- dhyper(x[i+1],m,n,k)`?

Comment: Precisly, have edited it now. Basically I just want to use the index number of the element 'k' in 'p' as the first variable in the dhyper function.

Comment: That looks like it should work. Have you tested it?

Comment: I get the error "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length". And the probabilities are all wrong as well..

Comment: I suggest reverting back to the original code and providing the expected result.

Comment: If you want a vector where each element is its index, you could also use ```p <- seq(0, K)```. I don't know what else you want to do inside that loop, but since loops are pretty slow in R, you might want to avoid them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution if I understand your expected output:

```
K <- 11
p <- rep(0, K + 1)
for (k in 0:K) {
  p[k + 1] <- k
}
```

Which returns:

```
[1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Comment: Oddly enough, it only returns 0s for me..

Comment: Sorry, I should have removed the `return(p)`. Try it again after removing that line.

Comment: Yes! Thanks a million. Now let's see if this will work in a function.

Comment: Sweet! Glad it's working. If this answers your question, feel free to click the green checkmark to show that the question is resolved.